# SQL Query doesn't return nulls in group by/aggregate?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms, sql-server-2017

I have this SQL query that returns a sum of a product sku per day, per store. It skips stores/names that don't return any values.

Currently the output is:

```
day     location sku totalSold
1/1/18     1      1      2
1/2/18     2      2      1
1/4/18     1      4      3
```

I want the output to be more like:

```
day     location sku totalSold
1/1/18     1      1      2
1/1/18     1      2      0
1/1/18     1      3      0
1/1/18     1      4      3
1/1/18     2      1      2
1/1/18     2      2      0
1/1/18     2      3      0
1/1/18     2      4      0
1/2/18     1      1      2
1/2/18     1      2      0
1/2/18     1      3      0
```

This is my current sql query:

```
SELECT tb1.timestamp, tb1.store, tbl2.sku, SUM(CAST(tbl2.quantity as integer)) as 'totalSold'
FROM tb1
LEFT JOIN tbl2 on tbl1.id = tbl2.id
WHERE tbl2.sku IN (select sku from tbl3) --tbl3 is a view w/ list of skunames
GROUP BY tbl1.Timestamp, YEAR(timestamp), MONTH(timestamp), DAY(timestamp), tbl1.store, tbl2.sku
```

Comment: take tbl2 conditions out of the where clause, into the join's `ON` clause. otherwise the left join behavior is modified and the resultset will contain only records from tb1 where the tb2 conditions are also fulfilled.
the # does not start a comment, so the code as you posted it would not parse.

Comment: I'm guessing you want to cross join your dates/locations/skus then use a left join to get totalsold. There's a number of ways you could do this, depending on the actual requirement (for some reason you have a sku of 4 in the current output that doesn't show up in the desired output so I'm not sure what the go with that is).

Comment: Thank you!! I hastily added the comment in this question with python but it's not in the actual query at all.

Comment: what happens when you take out the where clause?

Comment: @MEdwin it would return for all sku's in tbl2 (thousands) whereas I only want about 30 returned, and tbl3 is a view of just those 30 skus.

Comment: okay, good. I understand. But in your result, you have tb1.store in the query, but the output you presented it is missing. Could you be grouping by field with lots of null values?

Comment: You can use this link to improve your question so you will get better quality answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

It was answered somewhat in the comments, but for future readers, here is the script you would use and why it is important to do that.

```
SELECT tb1.timestamp, tb1.store, tbl2.sku, SUM(CAST(tbl2.quantity as integer)) as 'totalSold'
FROM tb1
LEFT JOIN tbl2 on tbl1.id = tbl2.id AND tbl2.sku IN (select sku from tbl3) --tbl3 is a view w/ list of skunames
GROUP BY tbl1.Timestamp, YEAR(timestamp), MONTH(timestamp), DAY(timestamp), tbl1.store, tbl2.sku
```

The original query forced the LEFT JOIN to be treated like an INNER JOIN because only records returned by the join could be evaluated for the WHERE clause conditions. By moving the section starting with tbl2.sku into the LEFT JOIN, the conditions previously in the WHERE clause get evaluated on the table before the join is evaluated (this may not be technically correct, but it is how it appears to us).

Comment: Thank you. This also does not account for any null data (or 0's) which it needs to. So I've added a cross join in there too and now I've run out of temp run storage.

Comment: If you add the scripts to create the tables and fill them with data that can be used to generate your expected results, I will update my query to produce the results.